# Как достать изменённый объект из функции события?

Tags: javascript

Как переписать/дописать код, чтобы получить дату в дальнейшем использовании(сделать не локальной)?

```
<input type="text" name="depdate" id="depdate" >

<script>
var supDep = new Date();
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

input.oninput = function (){
 var  valInInput = (document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value.match(/\d+/g));
 supDep.setHours(valInInput[0],valInInput[1],valInInput[2],valInInput[3]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var currentValue;
document.getElementById('depdate').oninput = function (){
  // this - измененный инпут:
  currentValue = this.value;
  console.log(currentValue);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="depdate" id="depdate" >
```

Comment: Как сделать так, что бы достать дату из локальной переменной во внешний код?